# Phonegap App not Running javascript elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, phonegap-build

So I have a code that runs the css and html fine in phonegap, but the javascript items do not function.  For example I'm making a To Do app, but the button will not save my new item, or click to delete.

**css code**

```
body
{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color:#D4D0B4;
}

h1
{
    background-color:#626b5e;
    font-size:1em;
    color:#F5F6F5;
    line-height:2em;
    text-align:center;

}

#newTaskInput, #addNewTask
{
    display:block;
    width:98%;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#757769;
    border:0;
    height;2em;
    font-size:1em;
    color:#F5F6F5;
}

#taskList
{
    margin-top:10px;
}

#taskList > li
{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF, #F6F6F7);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFF, #F6F6F7);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFF, #F6F6F7);
    background: linear-gradient(#FFF, #F6F6F7);
    border:1px solid #BBB6AF
    line-height:2em;
    color:#929292;
    margin-top:2px;
}

#taskList span
{
    margin-left:5px;
}

.done
{
    text-decoration:line-through;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="type/css" href="css/reset.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Todo List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Todo List</h1>
        <div id="newTaskSection">
            <input type="text" id="newTaskInput" placeholder="New Task">
            <button id="addNewTask">Add</button>
        </div>
        <ul id="taskList">
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

**javascript**

```
var taskList = new Array();


$( document ).ready(function(){
    var $newTaskInput = $('#newTaskInput');
    var $taskList = $('#taskList');
    var taskTouchStart;
    var taskTouchEnd;
    var taskTouchStartX;
    var taskTouchEndX;

    if( window.localStorage )
    {
        taskList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('taskList'));
    }

    if(null !== taskList)
    {
        for(i=0;i<taskList.length;i++)
        {
            var newTask = '<li data-key="' + taskList[1].key + '"><span>' + taskList[i].task + '</span></li>';
            $taskList.append(newTask);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        taskList = new Array();
    }

    $('#addNewTask').on('click', function(){
        var key = Date.now();
        var newTask = '<li data-key="' + key + '"><span>' + $newTaskInput.val() + '</span></li>';
        $taskList.append( newTask );
        taskList.push({key:key, task:$newTaskInput.val(), done:false});
        if(window.localStorage)
        {
            window.localStorage.setItem('taskList', JSON.stringify(taskList));
        }
        $newTaskInput.val('');
    });

    $taskList.on('touchstart', 'li', function(e){
        var start = document.elementFromPoint( e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX, e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY);
        taskTouchStart = $(start).attr('data-key');
        taskTouchStartX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    });

    $taskList.on('touchend', 'li', function(e){
        var $end;
        var $this = $(this);
        var end = document.elementFromPoint( e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX, e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY);
        $end = $(end);
        taskTouchEnd = $end.attr('data-key');
        taskTouchEndX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
        if(taskTouchStart == taskTouchEnd)
        {
            if(taskTouchStartX < taskTouchEndX)
            {
                if($this.hasClass('done'))
                {
                    $this.removeClass('done');
                }
                else
                {
                    $this.addClass('done');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                taskList = $.grep(taskList, function(e){ return e.key != taskTouchEnd;});
                if(window.localStorage)
                {
                window.localStorage.setItem('taskList', JSON.stringify(taskList));
                }
                $end.remove();
            }
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: You don't really mean *Java* in the title, do you?

Comment: I don't spot the error right now but does the $( document ).ready(function(){ trigger ? I usually write down alerts between lines so I can tell where it stops working

Answer (score 0):

Simplified form of the done/not done handler in the code below, which would replace your current on('touchstart.. and on('touchend... blocks and remove a lot of complexity:

Additionally, you have a 1 where there should be an i in your display block (unless I mistook the purpose), and you're not setting the done class for tasks from localStorage which are marked such.

Changes commented in the code below, which would replace the JS you posed above.

Also, apologies, but I've mixed jQuery and vanilla JS, and only went so far as to get a working example, you'll have to work further on validation on what not, hopefully this gets you going.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){

    var $newTaskInput = $('#newTaskInput');
    var $taskList     = $('#taskList');

    if( window.localStorage ){
        taskList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('taskList'));
    }

    if(null !== taskList){

        for(i=0;i<taskList.length;i++){

            // Should we add the 'done' class to these items?
            var newTaskClass = (taskList[i].done)? 'done': '';

            // taskList[1].key to taskList[i].key ??? or am I missing something?
            var newTask = '<li data-key="' + taskList[i].key + '" class="' + newTaskClass + '"><span>' + taskList[i].task + '</span></li>';
            $taskList.append(newTask);
        }
    }

    else {
        taskList = new Array();
    }

    $('#addNewTask').on('click', function(){
        var key = Date.now();
        var newTask = '<li data-key="' + key + '"><span>' + $newTaskInput.val() + '</span></li>';
        $taskList.append( newTask );
        taskList.push({key:key, task:$newTaskInput.val(), done:false});
        if(window.localStorage)
        {
            window.localStorage.setItem('taskList', JSON.stringify(taskList));
        }
        $newTaskInput.val('');
    });

    // Replaces the 'touchstart/end' handlers
    $(document).on('click', '#taskList li', function(e){

        var task = $(this);

        // Update the li class
        if (task.hasClass('done')){
            task.removeClass('done');
        } else {
            task.addClass('done');
        }

        // Find the item by its key property (assumes key exists / no duplicates)
        var itemToUpdate = taskList.filter(function(item){
            return item.key === task.data('key');
        })[0];

        // If true, make false, if false, make ture
        itemToUpdate.done = !itemToUpdate.done;

        // Over-write the task list in local storage
        window.localStorage.setItem('taskList', JSON.stringify(taskList));
    });
});
```